# Free Rest API to retrieve current datetime as string (timezone irrelevant)

Tags: rest, api, time, timer, timezone-offset

I am seeking a reliable **REST API** that can provide **world time and time zone information across platforms**.

I need the current time as a string. I'd like it to **return the result in under a second**, regardless of the user's location worldwide.

Among other implementations I want to use this for a consistent countdown timer, to be more accurate than a user's [possibly-inaccurate] computer time. It can be GMT or another time zone, as long as the time zone and offset is specified, like `2012-11-05 16:16:50 EST`.

I would build this API myself, but have concerns of **potential latency issues** (as well as inelegance) when filtering someone through a whole big software stack like Rails just to return a simple `String`.

Excessive latency for users far away from the US east coast would offset the benefit of accuracy that the task requires.

Any suggestions and/or examples are appreciated.

Comment: This is rough, but works:  `wget -q -O - www.worldtimeserver.com/time-zones/cst | grep "Server Time"`.  Obviously you can change the timezone.  Getting the date takes a bit more work, but it's in the page.  Also you can pull the time value if you grep for serverTimeStamp tho you'll have to do some conversion obviously

Comment: See also [`http://worldclockapi.com/`](http://worldclockapi.com/)... free, no registration, simple.  **Examples:** [UTC Time Now](http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now) and ["Is Seattle/PST on Daylight Savings on April 20, 2019?"](http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/2019-04-20).

Comment: @ashleedawg: The question is still off topic. Did you miss the  *Some questions are still off-topic, **even if they fit into one of the categories listed above*** part, perhaps? Questions that are not about software tools commonly used by programmers are off-topic no matter what, recommendation questions are off topic even if they are about software tools. Number of views never factor in determining if a post is off topic.

Comment: @ashleedawg I deleted your comment, as though it was well intentioned, it was misguided. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for friend: http://worldtimeapi.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Rails, you can just make an empty file in the public folder and use ajax to get that. Then [parse the headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript) for the Date header. Files in the Public folder bypass the Rails stack, and so have lower latency.

Comment: 503: Over Quota - This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later.

Comment: Blocked by chrome (and other modern browsers?) unless server also return additional headers allowing it.

Comment: 1/ Required CORS headers for such a cross domain request:  
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (or your domain)  
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date  
2/ Observed on Android 4.1.2: Access-Control-Expose-Headers is ignored. You will get the Content-Type header only. So for this reason avoid cross domain request.  
3/ If you repeat the ajax request and the browser has cached the response, you may not receive the Date header. So if you need to perform this request several time, I suggest to add a random query string to your ajax request url to prevent caching.

Answer (score 21):

TimezoneDb provides a free API: http://timezonedb.com/api

GenoNames also has a RESTful API available to get the current time for a given location: http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html.

You can use Greenwich, UK if you'd like GMT.

Comment: Both of these suck, unfortunately. GeoNames doesn't return seconds, which I need. And I've only been able to get a successful response from TimezoneDb once, mostly it just gives me a 403 Forbidden (even though I'm definitely using the proper format and the key they gave me). I wish these worked!

Comment: Are you using Javascript on the frontend? This is doable through Javascript without the use of additionally APIs or frameworks. I would personally go that route rather than relying on a 3rd-party API.

Comment: I am using JavaScript. And it works, except that the user's computer time can be inaccurate by several minutes. That's why I'd prefer to get the time via a low-latency API call which is guaranteed to be accurate within the deviation of the mentioned latency.

Answer (score 8):

This API gives you the current time and several formats in JSON - https://market.mashape.com/parsify/format#time.  Here's a sample response:

```
{
  "time": {
    "daysInMonth": 31,
    "millisecond": 283,
    "second": 42,
    "minute": 55,
    "hour": 1,
    "date": 6,
    "day": 3,
    "week": 10,
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2013,
    "zone": "+0000"
  },
  "formatted": {
    "weekday": "Wednesday",
    "month": "March",
    "ago": "a few seconds",
    "calendar": "Today at 1:55 AM",
    "generic": "2013-03-06T01:55:42+00:00",
    "time": "1:55 AM",
    "short": "03/06/2013",
    "slim": "3/6/2013",
    "hand": "Mar 6 2013",
    "handTime": "Mar 6 2013 1:55 AM",
    "longhand": "March 6 2013",
    "longhandTime": "March 6 2013 1:55 AM",
    "full": "Wednesday, March 6 2013 1:55 AM",
    "fullSlim": "Wed, Mar 6 2013 1:55 AM"
  },
  "array": [
    2013,
    2,
    6,
    1,
    55,
    42,
    283
  ],
  "offset": 1362534942283,
  "unix": 1362534942,
  "utc": "2013-03-06T01:55:42.283Z",
  "valid": true,
  "integer": false,
  "zone": 0
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was looking for something a bit more simple (I really just wanted a simple string), but this is good to know.

Comment: Link has changed. Now it is: https://market.mashape.com/parsify/format#time

Comment: Stopped wotking again