# How to obtain local time from Modem

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, samsung-smart-tv, ntp

I want to develop an application for my smart tv which does not have the ability to synchronize local time automatically as it does in any desktop/laptop operating system or such as the mobile operating system. I do not know from where and how do I get the time automatically from the internet or local modem

Answer (score 1):

You can go with web-services for both geo-location & time:

- http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation - get the location
- http://timezonedb.com/api - get the time

Also see [Free Rest API to get current time as string (timezone irrelevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant)

Comment: It is nice but i do not want to depend on third party services. Is there any protocol specifically to talk to modem for giving time?