# Find the actual DateTime.Now on Windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, datetime, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have got a problem where I need to find the actual datetime even if user changes the datetime of device intentionally without hitting any service. I know this is possible as Candy Crash game does this. Any help will be hightly appreciated

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

You should get the time from another public service or website, because DateTime.Now get that time that is set in a local computer or phone.