# Check if date is correct in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I am grabbing the current date by NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970. However, I am concerned that the user will change the date on the phone to mess with my app. So I was wondering which of the two options below is a more suitable fix

1. Is there some sort of Apple way to grab the current date from an apple server.
2. Is there a good and reliable API where I can grab current date?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TIMEAPI` available at [www.timeapi.org](http://www.timeapi.org/)

You can retrieve the current time in UTC [here.](http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now)