# Javascript Unix timestamp different on each device

Tags: javascript, date, unix, timezone, epoch

Hey I noticed something weird while developing an app that is supposed to run synchronized to a server.

JavaScript's unix timestamp is different on each device! :O
**The experiment:** I open the chrome dev console and did 2 commands:

```
new Date()
```

And

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Both of the commands are executed at the EXACT same time (I pressed enter on both computers at the **very exact same time**)

The output was as follows:

**Computer 1:**
[image]

**Computer 2**
[image]

It is highly likely that this problem occurs due to one computer being Central Europe Standard Time and the other W. Europe Standard Time, but I can't ask all my clients to just go to Central Europe standard time.

**Is there a way to get the same unix timestamp on both devices regardless of their clock if both are called at the exact same time?**

Comment: I think that only way to make sure you have the same timestamp on different clients is to get it from the same remote source (web service or similar)

Comment: It's only off by about 16 seconds, I doubt time zones are to blame. Maybe one machine's clock is off?

Answer (score 3):

Both computers probably have a different time, did the user set it up manually?
you can use a web service, see 
[Free Rest API to get current time as string (timezone irrelevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant)

Comment: Yes that is right, I was just wondering if I could get a unified timestamp for the purpose of measuring the time it took for an internet request to reach the server

Comment: @ErikBrandsma if the answer solved your problem then consider marking it as accepted answer