# Get the Official Date and Time from an external URL

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the Official Date and Time from an external URL and my PHP script does not return the values I want. Would you be so kind as to help me please?

```
<?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
require_once('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.cenam.mx/hora_oficial/');

// get and show the Mexico Center's Time
$hcentro = $html->find('div[id=hcentro]', 0)->innertext;
echo 'hcentro: '. $hcentro;

// get and show the Mexico Center's Date 
$fcentro = $html->find('div[id=fcentro]', 0)->innertext;
echo 'fcentro: '. $fcentro;
?>
```

The result I get simply is the following:
hcentro: fcentro:

Nothing. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Please Help Me Guys

Answer (score 0):

The `hcentro` `div` is empty:

```
Tiempo del Centro</strong> 
<div style="FONT-SIZE: 15pt;font-weight: bold; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman;  " id="hcentro">
</div>
```

Same for the other `div`.

The reason is the values are created via javascript. You might want to dig deeper into the javascript code.

Why don't you use a [REST service](https://market.mashape.com/parsify/format#time) or even [a local public file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant)

Comment: Thank's laur Ivan, the curious thing is that using vb6, I can get the time and date of the external url with the htmlDom object.