# Verify date online in Inno Setup for expiring installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have Inno Setup code to show error message when installing a setup developed using Inno Setup. The error message will shown when date of expire happens.

The code is as follows:

```pascal
const MY_EXPIRY_DATE_STR = '20171112'; // Date format: yyyymmdd

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  // If current date exceeds MY_EXPIRY_DATE_STR then return false and
  // exit Installer.
  Result :=
    CompareStr(GetDateTimeString('yyyymmdd', #0,#0), MY_EXPIRY_DATE_STR) <= 0;

  if not Result then
    MsgBox('Due to some problem', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Now my question is that I want verify the date using internet, not by local system date.

Answer (score 1):

Use some online service to retrieve the time (or build your own service).

See [Free Rest API to retrieve current datetime as string (timezone irrelevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13240530/850848).

Make sure, you use HTTPS, so that it not easy to bypass the check.

The following example uses [TimeZoneDB service](https://timezonedb.com/).

You have to set your own API key (that you get after a free registration).

```pascal
const
  TimezoneDbApiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';

function GetOnlineTime: string;
var
  Url: string;
  XMLDocument: Variant;
  XMLNodeList: Variant;
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  S: string;
  P: Integer;
begin
  try
    // Retrieve XML from with current time in London
    // See https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone
    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    Url :=
      'https://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone?key=' + TimezoneDbApiKey +
      '&format=xml&by=zone&zone=Europe/London';
    WinHttpReq.Open('GET', Url, False);
    WinHttpReq.Send('');
    if WinHttpReq.Status <> 200 then
    begin
      Log('HTTP Error: ' + IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' +
          WinHttpReq.StatusText);
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('HTTP Response: ' + WinHttpReq.ResponseText);

      // Parse the XML
      XMLDocument := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
      XMLDocument.async := False;
      XMLDocument.loadXML(WinHttpReq.ResponseText);

      if XMLDocument.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
      begin
        Log('The XML file could not be parsed. ' + XMLDocument.parseError.reason);
      end
        else
      begin
        XMLDocument.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
        XMLNodeList := XMLDocument.selectNodes('/result/formatted');
        if XMLNodeList.length > 0 then
        begin
          S := Trim(XMLNodeList.item[0].text);
          // Remove the time portion
          P := Pos(' ', S);
          if P > 0 then
          begin
            S := Copy(S, 1, P - 1);
            // Remove the dashes to get format yyyymmdd
            StringChange(S, '-', '');
            if Length(S) <> 8 then
            begin
              Log('Unexpected date format: ' + S);
            end
              else
            begin
              Result := S;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  except
    Log('Error: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
  end;

  if Result = '' then
  begin
    // On any problem, fallback to local time
    Result := GetDateTimeString('yyyymmdd', #0, #0);
  end;
end;
```