# Finding exact Date Time in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an android app and I need to get the EXACT date and time using android studio. There are many questions which have solutions to this, but I realised that all of them give the phone's time which can be edited by the user. I need the exact world-standard time.

Currently, the code I'm using is this:

```
DateFormat dfgmt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
            dfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8:00"));
            String nowTime = dfgmt.format(new Date());
```

But this is giving me the time which is at times tweaked by the user. Anyone has a way to get the exact time?

Comment: There is probably an API u can call to get the time...or maybe hit google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

There are few different approaches that you could follow, based on whether you have access to the internet and/or GPS, and whether you want this functionality to work offline.

1. As others have suggested, you could use an online service to get the official time. For example, [TimezoneDB](https://timezonedb.com/api) provides such a REST API.
2. If you need to access the time offline, read the time from the **GPS** provider, which returns the time in UTC format. Check [Location.getTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()).
3. Use a combination of an online service to get the time once and combine it with [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#elapsedRealtime()) to get the actual real time after that, even if the device is offline.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an external service for this. You could set up a simple REST API or use someone else's (check this post which gives an example of one [Free Rest API to get current time as string (timezone irrelevant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant)) to make HTTP requests and get the time irrelevant of what is set on the user's phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the time to a remote server.

This will grant you that the time is not setted manually by the user and is not influenced by the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd-party NTP client library to get current time from an NTP server.

E.g. [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) has a class for that.