# How to get the exact date if i change the device date?

Tags: android

Now the exact date is 8-Jun-2018

But if I change the device date to future or past (i.e 21-Jun-2018 or 21-Feb-2018)?
How to get exact date i.e 8-Jun-2018?

Comment: Use can use a rest call, here you can get the [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant)

Comment: is any way without using API

Comment: The actual question is: `Why would you ever change the device date?`

Comment: ex: if my api should hit on a particular date, if the user changes the date

Comment: you can listen to date changes using broadcastreceiver, adn re-scedule event based on change difference, or you can sync time from the internet

Answer (score 1):

For exact date you can try with timeZone. You can get the time according to current location through GoogleAPI also.