# Get current time from external ressource

Tags: javascript, json

I used JavaScript object `Date()` to get current time but I realize users can change their system time to change the value of the object.

That's why I need to get current time from an external resource (JSON would be preferable) so this will prevent users from changing their current time on their device.

Is anyone aware of any sort of things like this?

Google didn't help me much. This would be highly helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-get-current-time-as-string-timezone-irrelevant

Comment: use ajax to call some server-side API to return a time. So as long as you trust that server's time report you can use it instead.